# git-ftp doesn't push changes to ftp

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I'm trying to use [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) to push files to an FTP server. The server already has files on it, that were uploaded via some different software (GUI drag-n-drop). The Git repository is running on BitBucket, and all of that side of things is working fine. I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.2 using Terminal.

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/develop/man/git-ftp.1.md) to apply a .git-ftp.log file to the server by running `git-ftp catchup` - that worked fine and the file appeared on the server. However when I make a change locally, I commit in the usual way, then attempt to upload the change using `git-ftp push`, it tells me 'Everything is up to date'.

If I try `git-ftp push -a` then it tells me 'There are 1 files to sync' (regardless of how many I actually changed), then 'Last deployment changed to ', but then my changes still aren't uploaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update: the problem appears to be due to the .git-ftp-ignore file, which evidently uses different syntax to a standard .gitignore file. Currently trying to work out what it is in the file that's tripping this up

Comment: A line that I use generally in .gitignore appears to be the issue: `\._*`

Comment: have you done the initial `git ftp init` command, to get the ball rolling? Also, in your `~/repo/.git/config` file do you have something like this? `[git-ftp]
    user = you
    url = ip.add.res.s/public_html/repo
    password = "xxxsupersecretpassword"`

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Git-ftp ignores all files that match regular expressions defined in the `.git-ftp-ignore` file. One of these two patterns should ignore your OSX files:

```
^\._.*
^.\._.*
```

You can use the `--dry-run` option to test what would be uploaded.

Alternatively and probably better would be to update Git-ftp. Newer versions use shell glob patterns similar to the ones in `.gitignore`. The new pattern would be:

```
._*
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [git-ftp installation and configuration](http://www.codingsips.com/install-configure-git-ftp-windows/) very easy and with full details and almost all possibilities like for your case you have to run
`git ftp catchup`
for the first time insted of
`git ftp init`
after first time as normal you have to run
`git ftp push`